# Как сравнить значения values из словаря и значения в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

На входе нам даются следующие данные:

```
4
A
B : A
C : A
D : B C
4
A B
B D
C D
D A
```

Код вот такой:

```
n=int(input())
d={}
    for i in range(n):
    line=input().split(':')
    if len(line) == 1 :
        d[line[0]] = ['']
    else:
        d[line[0].strip()] = line[1].split()

z = int(input())
list = []      
for i in range(z):
    request = input().split()
    list.append(request[0])
```

Словарь у нас будет вида:

```
{'C': ['A'], 'D': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['A'], 'A': ['']}
```

Список будет вот такой:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

И сам вопрос: В конце кода я хочу написать что-то типа

```
for j in list:
if list in d.values():
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Но получу на выходе везде "No", т.к. будут сравниваться 2 объекта 'A' и A, вместо A и А (без кавычек). Как провернуть эту проверку?

Comment: Что-то похожее видел на степике :)

Comment: это именно оттуда)

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос и уберите всё до слов *"Словарь у нас будет вида:"*--это не имеет отношения к вопросу в заголовке. В конце добавьте какой результат ожидаете от сравнения (явно укажите `моё_сравние(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A']) == 'Yes'` или `моё_сравние(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A']) == 'No'` -- что вы хотите получить и почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виноват, поправил. Этот код вроде работает правильно.

```
d = {'C': ['A'], 'D': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['A'], 'A': ['']}
list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

dlist = [val for sublist in d.values() for val in sublist]
print(dlist)
for j in list:  
    print(j)
    if j in dlist:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Comment: В вашем примере будет всегда даваться ответ  "да", хотя значение D из списка в значениях словаря нет, и ответ не должен быть "да".